# How do 6 people already have the 'Enthusiast' badge?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

I just noticed that 6 users have the ['Enthusiast' badge](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/badges/22/enthusiast) already, which requires you to visit the site each day for 30 days.  However, the site is only 23 days old, right?  One user's [profile](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/users/106/pulsehead) says he/she has been a member for 23 days.

Is there something else going on?  Was there a pre-private beta, that started longer than 23 days ago?  If there was, why would the site think this person has only been a member for 23 days?

Some of the users have been members much longer than 23 days, which I suspect is because of the merger with brewadvice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct - the people awarded the badge were previously active on BrewAdvice for 30 days straight at some point.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  But then how did @pulsehead get it?  (Not to pick on pulsehead, I am just confused how he/she got the badge, since the system thinks he/she has only been a member for 23 days.)

Comment: The "member for" doesn't account for the merge.  It's a member for date based on this site only.

Comment: Well, in that case, how did some of the members get 'member for' several months?

Comment: @pkaeding, I got it because I was a member of BrewAdvice.  Then I found out about HB.SE.com and created another account.  Interestingly enough all my BA questions that were marked as answered on BA had that marking removed on migrating to HB.SE.  Annoying, but fixed inside of 10 minutes, so easier to work around than submit a bug.